# unify build number on appcenter with react native iOS / android apps

Tags: version, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms) with a react native project, working ok.

I need to integrate the same build number for iOS and Android, how to do that?

At the moment my next build ID for android is 211 and for iOS is 135

how to unify on both platforms?